# SystemUpdate() in list item update

Tags: list, splistitem, update

What's the advantage/reason for using `SystemUpdate()` over `Update()` when list data update?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We might have to manipulate/update the data without changing the Modified or Modified By fields to meet the business needs and also retaining the document/Item status without incrementing the version is also important aspect to be considered. In such cases `SystemUpdate()` method of `SPListItem` can be leveraged.

This basically updates the content database with the changes that are made to the list item without changing the Modified or Modified By fields.

Overridden Methods

- SystemUpdate() – Updates the database with changes made to the list
  item without changing the Modified or Modified By fields.
- SystemUpdate(true) – Updates the database with changes made to the
  list item without changing the Modified or Modified By fields, and
  the item version is increased.
- SystemUpdate(false) – Updates the database with changes made to the
  list item without changing the Modified or Modified By fields, and
  the item version is not increased.

Calling the method `SystemUpdate()` is same as calling `SystemUpdate(Boolean)` with false.

http://sharepointhangout.com/simple-fix-splistitem-systemupdate-boolean-true-vs-false-explained/

Comment: Now you just need to mark your own answer as an answer :) Job well done!